# Union Types are not inferred properly in flowtype

Tags: javascript, redux, flowtype

[flowtype](http://flowtype.org) is not able to identify the following given types when I use them as argument of a function like the following:

```
/* @flow */

type Action =
    { type: "SELECT", componentToSelect: string }
    | { type: "UPDATE", componentToUpdate: string };

function dispatch(action: Action) {
  console.log(action.componentToSelect);
}
dispatch({
   type: "SELECT",
   componentToSelect: "anything"
});
```

The error message is as below:

> `componentToSelect`. Property not found in object type

Code online [here](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCAxhgJZwB2YAvKgJADeY2+AXGAEQDKAogDK8AwgBVOAGjDE4AWxxU8lDCLjc8MPKQ4BnDACcylAOZgAvgwA+YZqzwdOAVQAKAEUIjeEqbPmVFyuAccABMAQww7MF0DYzMAbnQoAFdKUgpqYLJtHHDiAAsAClC0qg4ScioASmtUMG9KbTgNADp4IyKSymbpOQUlFTUNUkqE80zs3MLGWrrbez5BUQkZ716-ftV1TQx7UMosDDzDI05UUxGgA)

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I am getting an error and I am investigating what I am doing wrong or how should I fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dispacth function expect an Action, but there is no certitude that the action has a property **componentToSelect**. 
I should first do a check on the type.

```
function dispatch(action: Action) {
  if (action.type === 'SELECT')
    console.log(action.componentToSelect);
}
```

View it [online](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCAxhgJZwB2YAvKgJADeY2+AXGAEQDKAogDK8AwgBVOAGjDE4AWxxU8lDCLjc8MPKQ4BnDACcylAOZgAvgwA+YZqzwdOAVQAKAEUIjeEqbPmVFyuAccABMAQww7MF0DYzMAbnQoAFdKUgpqYLJtHHDiAAsAClC0qg4ScioASmtUMDAyKDAiksoAOltaGhowAHI+QVEeytqwemlKbTgNVvgjZoq26TkFJRU1DVJKhPNM7NzCxhGWXEieAWExcSOl33819U0Me1DKLAw8wyNOVFMtoA)